# For each cell in a column, check multiple matches in the next column and then highlight them

Tags: excel, vba, match

In an excel sheet, I have insurance policy numbers in one column and endorsements against each of them in the next column with the same policy number. Then there is the third column with outstanding amount against each policy and endorsement.

I want a macro that checks for policy matches in the next column and then checks if the outstanding amounts are both non-zero and equal.

I'm working on this code currently:

```
Sub Outstandingknockoff() 
Dim Cell As Range 
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For Each Cell In Range("D2:D" & LR)
Match = Application.Match(Cell, Range("e2:e" & LR), 0)
If Match <> 0 And Cell.Offset(0, 16) <> 0 And Cell.Offset(0, 16) = -Range("T" & Match + 1) Then
On Error Resume Next
Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Match.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the code in your question you are working on to solve this if you would like help.

Comment: Please see now. I have added the code I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double loop could work.

```
Sub DoubleLoop3()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim a As Range, c As Range
    Set rng1 = Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    Set rng2 = Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    Columns("D:F").Interior.Color = xlNone

    For Each c In rng1.Cells
        For Each a In rng2.Cells
            If c = a And a.Offset(, 1) <> 0 Then
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                a.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                a.Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next a
    Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @daveexcel. This seems to work. But one more thing, I wanted to add another condition too that would check if a.Offset(0, 15) = -c.Offset(0, 16). But the headers of the columns are preventing it because they are strings, not integers. How to work out this?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand.
`a.Offset(0, 15) = -c.Offset(0, 16)` would be the same cell would it not?

Comment: An IF with IsNumber to skip strings worked. Thank you so much. <3

Comment: But this is not checking for multiple matches of rng1 in rng2. Because there are cases where one policy is knocked off by multiple partial endorsements. Is there any way of checking that?

Answer (score 0):

@Adnan Ahmad have in mind the the title of your third column has mistake. You could use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowA As Long, LastRowB As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim Policy_No As String, Outstanding As Double

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRowA

            If IsNumeric(.Range("C" & i).Value) Then

                Policy_No = .Range("A" & i).Value
                Outstanding = .Range("C" & i).Value

                For y = 2 To LastRowB
                    If IsNumeric(.Range("C" & y).Value) Then

                        If (.Range("B" & y).Value = Policy_No) And (.Range("C" & y).Value + Outstanding = 0) Then
                            .Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                            .Range("B" & y).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                            .Range("C" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                            .Range("C" & y).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                        End If

                    End If

                Next y

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Error1004. Though I didn't have time to try this one because Dave's solution worked for me already but I appreciate your time and effort. Thank you once again <3